# Decreasing processing time for shp map choropleth

Tags: r, plot, geolocation, maps, shapefile

Im making a choropleth map from Argentina in which Im going to plot some Data.

I can put the map up with no problems and also plot some data on it. For example like this:

[image]

The problem is I think R is rendering the map in too high quality (which I dont need) and the processing time is taking ages. (~3 minutes) To display that choropleth. This is the code im using.

```
arg_shp <- readOGR("ARG_adm_shp/ARG_adm1.shp", "ARG_adm1")


puntos <- read.csv("puntos.csv", sep = ",", header = T)

arg_pv <- fortify(arg_shp, region = "NAME_1")

gg <- ggplot() 
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=arg_pv, map=arg_pv, 
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + ggthemes::theme_map()



gg + geom_map(data = puntos, aes(map_id = Provincia, fill = Puntos), 
              map = arg_pv)
```

Or alternatively I have tried using something like this to see if it made any difference.

```
ggplot() + geom_map(data = puntos, aes(map_id = Provincia, fill = Puntos), 
                    map = arg_pv) + expand_limits(x = arg_pv$long , y = arg_pv$lat)
```

After trying some data im well aware that the code that is making the processing take long is obviously the

> expand_limits

As is taking the information for all the 259k data points in the fortify table.

Any ideas to cope with this?

Comment: In `ggplot() + geom_map(data = puntos, aes(map_id = Provincia, fill = Puntos), map = arg_pv) + expand_limits(x = arg_pv$long , y = arg_pv$lat)`, I wonder if you would just need min and max of long and lat. Right now, it seems to me that you are using all values of long and lat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** for the new way ggplot2 mapping "works" O_o

This:

```
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(ggthemes)
library(viridis)
library(magrittr)

# as stated in the other answer, this is the same as your shapefile
arg_adm <- raster::getData('GADM', country='ARG', level=1)

# make the polygons a bit less verbose
gSimplify(arg_adm, 0.01, topologyPreserve=TRUE) %>% 
  SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(dat=arg_adm@data) -> arg_adm

# turn them into a data frame
arg_map <- fortify(arg_adm, region="NAME_1")

# use a gd projection for this region
arg_proj <- "+proj=aeqd +lat_0=-37.869859624840764 +lon_0=-66.533203125"

# reproducibly simulate some data
set.seed(1492)
puntos <- data.frame(id=c("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "Catamarca", "Chaco", "Chubut",
                          "Ciudad de Buenos Aires", "Corrientes", "Entre Ríos", "Formosa", 
                          "Jujuy", "La Pampa", "La Rioja", "Mendoza", "Misiones", "Neuquén", 
                          "Río Negro", "Salta", "San Juan", "San Luis", "Santa Cruz", 
                          "Santa Fe", "Santiago del Estero", "Tierra del Fuego", "Tucumán"),
                     value=sample(100, 24))

# plot it
gg <- ggplot() 

# necessary in the new world of ggplot2 mapping O_o
gg <- gg + geom_blank(data=arg_map, aes(long, lat))

# draw the base polygon layer
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=arg_map, map=arg_map, 
                    aes(map_id=id),
                    color="#b2b2b2", size=0.15, fill=NA)
# fill in the polygons
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=puntos, map=arg_map,
                    aes(fill=value, map_id=id),
                    color="#b2b2b2", size=0.15)

gg <- gg + scale_fill_viridis(name="Scale Title")
gg <- gg + coord_proj(arg_proj)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position=c(0.8, 0.1))
gg
```

[image]

Renders *really* fast on my system:

```
benchplot(gg)

##        step user.self sys.self elapsed
## 1 construct     0.000    0.000   0.000
## 2     build     0.029    0.002   0.031
## 3    render     0.206    0.006   0.217
## 4      draw     0.049    0.001   0.051
## 5     TOTAL     0.284    0.009   0.299
```

Try to follow the above idiom vs what you're doing or post the output of `dput(puntos)` into your question so it's reproducible. Also: the continued inclusion of the entire RStudio window in your questions is really neither helpful nor minimal.

Comment: Cant thank you enough. That renders really fast on me as well. Thanks a lot, why was the other rendering so slow?

Comment: Not entirely sure since I didn't try to replicate with your data & method. This is the "standard" way to do GIS operations using ggplot2. It's all about layers like in "real" GIS programs.

Comment: Got it. You made it look so simple.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I just realized that `geom_map()` does not take long and lat as x and y in aes(). I checked the examples of the function in the CRAN manual. Hadley used `expand_limits()`. Is this the only way we can specify long and lat in ggplot now? At least when we use geom_map(), this seems to be the only way. If you know anything, would you be able to share your knowledge?

Comment: @jazzurro _kinda_. lemme mock up something. i will say the latest CRAN release of ggplot2 feels like what VW did to their diesel cars.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Haha. I like that metaphor! Please let me know when you mock up something.

Comment: @jazzurro (et al) here ya go: http://rpubs.com/hrbrmstr/ggplot2_map_machinations. I think I covered the necessary fundamentals, but let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you for the link. `geom_blank(data=world, aes(x=long, y=lat)) `... It would be really nice to have long and lat in geom_map... I might put long and lat in the function since we can still draw a map. But, eventually we would need to use geom_blank, I think.

Comment: It's was a super-weird design choice but Hadley closed the issue I opened and we're stuck with it unless I build a `geom_map_the_way_it_should_be()` :-) #makegeommapgreatagain

Comment: @hrbrmstr Haha! I am happy to support and promote the function! This is really frustrating...

Comment: @jazzurro https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt now has `geom_cartogram()` which restores the old behaviour of `geom_map()`. I may add some things to it that I've been working around in `geom_map()` for a while. I also need to get the new geoms in it up on CRAN soon.

Comment: Cool! It's pretty late here. I gotta sleep. I'll check the link tomorrow. Thank you for your hard work to make geom_map lovers' lives. :)

Comment: @hrbrmstr Do you plan to implement cartogram through ggplot2? If so, this would be such a great idea. I have been using ScapeToad. I must say it takes some time to get new data. geom_cartogram() will be my good friend for sure. I look forward to checking your update in the `ggalt` package.

Comment: _technically_ encoding any statistics on a map is a cartogram ;-) also (technically) the `statebins` pkg i wrote is a form of cartogram :-) i'm not a huge fan of the distorted maps, but i can see what it wld take to bridge https://github.com/omegahat/Rcartogram & https://github.com/chrisbrunsdon/getcartr into a `geom_`